# Lenovo G50 cannot connect to Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, lenovo

I am new to Ubuntu. ^^

It seems I cannot connect to Wi-Fi. When I click on the Networking logo on the top bar, it only shows "Ethernet Network" and "disconnected".

- Version of Ubuntu is 14.04 LTS.
- I am using a Lenovo G50 laptop.
- Ubuntu is on a 32GB SanDisk Extreme USB 3.0.
- I chose to boot my USB in Boot Menu (<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>)
- On boot, I chose to try Ubuntu without installing it.
- Enable Networking is ticked.
- I did a little research and tried different methods, but they couldn't fix my problem.
- I learnt that there is this module called `wlan0` that sort of lets me connect to a Wi-Fi network, but it did not show up when I did `rfkill list all`.

---

Here are some information that may be useful.

`rfkill list all`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: Yes
        Soft blocked: no
```

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:d2:44:ad:17:6a
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 MB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback (bla bla bla)
```

`lspci -knn | grep 0280`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

`sudo rfkill -r ideapad-laptop`:

Some say this works but for me it just removed all modules.

`lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

---

Please do comment if you need any more information. As said before, I am a noob so I have little idea what info to give and what to solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38524/discussion-between-mitch-and-arceusmaster0493).

Answer (score 1):

try installing the bcmwl file from  the boot usb

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First connect your notebook with an ethernet cable to the wired network and install the Ubuntu system. After having finished boot into the installed Ubuntu operating system and install the proprietary BROADCOM wireless drivers. Open a terminal and execute these commands :

```
sudo apt get update  
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source  
sudo reboot
```